# Changing parameters while using plotCI in R. (Shift points left or right)

Tags: r, parameters, confidence-interval

I know that you can shift boxplots left or right on a graph by adding "at=1:6-0.2" or "at=1:6+0.2" to the code, but the same is not the case when I am using plotCI. Does anyone know how to perform this simple parameter adjustment? I know it has to be easy but there are very few questions about plotCI on here. It is in the package {gplots}. This is driving me crazy! Thanks for any help.
  -Alex

Answer (score 2):

If you want to shift *everything* (points and error bars) then all you need to do is add a small amount to the x parameter of plotCI:

```
plotCI(x=myx+0.2,y=...)
```

But that seems weird, so maybe you meant that you want to plot the *points* in the correct position, but shift the *error bars* slightly to the right? That still seems odd to me, but it can be done fairly easily by grabbing the code for plotCI, putting it in a wrapper function and adding a small offset parameter to your wrapper function that is passed to the relevant portion of the plotCI code.

Upon checking, that code for plotCI is a bit long, so I won't reproduce the whole thing here. Type plotCI at the console, and copy and paste the result in a text file, and call the function something new, like plotCI_offset. I believe if you then change the x coordinate parameters of the myarrow function call in the final if/else statement, you'll be golden.

The new function def would look like this:

```
plotCI_offset <- function (x, y = NULL, uiw, liw = uiw, ui, li, err = "y", ylim = NULL, 
xlim = NULL, type = "p", col = par("col"), barcol = col, 
pt.bg = par("bg"), sfrac = 0.01, gap = 1, lwd = par("lwd"), 
lty = par("lty"), labels = FALSE, add = FALSE, xlab, ylab, 
minbar, maxbar,offset=0.2, ...)
```

And I've quoted the altered bits of the function below:

```
if (!add) {
    if (invalid(labels) || labels == FALSE)
        #Add offset here to ensure plot window is right size
        plot(x+offset, y, ylim = ylim, xlim = xlim, col = col, xlab = xlab, 
            ylab = ylab, ...)
    else {
        plot(x, y, ylim = ylim, xlim = xlim, col = col, type = "n", 
            xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, ...)
        text(x, y, label = labels, col = col, ...)
    }
}
```

Then just below there alter this code as follows:

```
if (err == "y") {
    if (gap != FALSE) 
        gap <- strheight("O") * gap
    smidge <- par("fin")[1] * sfrac
    if (!is.null(li))
        #Add offset to CIs 
        myarrows(x+offset, li, x+offset, pmax(y - gap, li), col = barcol, 
            lwd = lwd, lty = lty, angle = 90, length = smidge, 
            code = 1)
    if (!is.null(ui)) 
        myarrows(x+offset, ui, x+offset, pmin(y + gap, ui), col = barcol, 
            lwd = lwd, lty = lty, angle = 90, length = smidge, 
            code = 1)
}
```

This only takes care of the case where the error bars are vertical. But the alterations for the horizontal case are similar.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
require(plotrix)
plotCI(1:3-0.1, m1, ui1, li1, xlab="Itens", ylab="Eta2",axes=FALSE)
axis(side=1,at=1:9,label=c(x1,x2,x3),padj=0,las=1)
axis(side=2)
```

Now do the same but like this:

```
plotCI(1:3+.1,m2, ui2, li2,axes=FALSE,col="blue",add=TRUE)
```

......

Answer (score 0):

I have a hack for that: you do not move your data points, rather, you **move the labels on the axes**!

e.g. you want to shift your data points to the right by 1 on x-axis, you hide the x-axis and redraw it with new labels:

```
plotCI(..., axes=F) # just ignore the warning
axis(side=1, at=0:99, labels=1,100)
```